# Make USB stick boot without going into PC BIOS

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, gparted

I wanted to have a portable version of Ubuntu that does not alter my Windows 10 installation and I have created a bootable 233 GByte USB3 stick with Ubuntu 20.04 installed.    It boots up into Ubuntu successfully but I have to go into the PC BIOS first to select the USB stick from the list displayed.  Otherwise the PC boots straight into Windows.  This is only a minor inconvenience but I would prefer it if the PC booted into Ubuntu directly if the USB is inserted but goes into Windows otherwise.  I know the BIOS is set to do this because, if I insert the original 4 GByte USB drive that I used to install Ubuntu it does boot straight into Ubuntu.

The USB3 stick has one partition with a 233.25 GByte Ext4 partition flagged boot,esp.  There is 1 MByte of unallocated space.  If sorting this out means that I need to re-install Ubuntu then I can live with the current situation but if there is a reasonably easy fix then I would like to try it.

Thanks

Comment: Many (but not all) computers show a temporary boot menu, when you press or tap (repeatedly) the F12 hotkey. And then you can select to boot your USB stick with Ubuntu. Other computers have other hotkeys. If you cannot find the hotkey for your computer (brand name and model), look in the user manual, and if you have no paper manual, find it via the internet.

Comment: You have to go into the BIOS, there is no alternative. That is what the BIOS was make fore. As a way to ask the user which storage element to boot from, or rather, the boot sequence.

Comment: Google Chromium and Brave seem to be pretty good alternatives; That is, they both support Chrome Store.

Comment: If you want to be able to boot either Windows or Ubuntu from Ubuntu's boot menu you need to install Ubuntu in the same BIOS or UEFI mode as Windows is installed in.